# path('accounts/', include(accounts.urls)), NameError: name 'accounts' is not defined

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-urls

I was just making a clone of ProductHunt.com website and while addressing the urls i am getting error as name error! when i type 'localhost:8000/accounts/signup' it should take me to a html page which i did for testing! the main urls.py looks like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from products import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('accounts/', include(accounts.urls)),
]
```

So by this it goes to the accounts folders urls.py which looks like:
    from django.urls import path, include
    from .import views

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup', views.signup, name="signup"),
    path('login', views.login, name="login"),
    path('logout', views.logout, name="logout"),
]
```

Then this goes to the views.py which looks like:
    from django.shortcuts import render

```
def signup(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html')

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')

def logout(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html')
```

Atlast my html is:

```
{% extends 'base.html %}

{% block content %}

signup!

{% endblock %}
```

Why am i getting a name error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Kiran\Desktop\producthunt-project\producthunt\urls.py", line 8,
 in <module>
    path('accounts/', include(accounts.urls)),
NameError: name 'accounts' is not defined
```

Help Me,
THANKS,

Comment: It's because of `include(accounts.urls)`. You need to import the name `account` or make it a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('accounts/', include(accounts.urls)),
]
```

with

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
]
```

And make sure that you have added 'accounts' in your installed apps.